# Unable to use ubuntu in dual boot with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I installed ubuntu after windows 7. After installation, when i restarted my pc, I didn't get any option to use ubuntu in boot menu. Now what can i do to use ununtu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed windows as well as ubuntu on your system and only ubuntu is booting at start up, than follow below steps.
1. Create a live USB/bootable UBS of Ubuntu and run it on live mode.
2. Now, install Boot-Repair.
3. after successful operation of boot-repair, restart your system. It will shows option to boot windows as well as ubuntu operating system.

Answer (score 0):

use live ubuntu cd

---

and install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

---

and fix it by Recommended repair in boot-repair menu